# Django Addform User

Tags: django

Hey in django admin there is a button "adduser". When I press it I want to show my custom Form. I tried to do the following.

at admin.py

```
  add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
  add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',), }),
)
```

P.S. I think the names interfered with the standard names. Once I renamed the fields from first_name to something custom it kidna started working.

at forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label='First name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label='Last name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email',)


def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

The only charfield that is editable that appears on teh admin-page is the "username". Others just have a label but not an edit-field which is odd. I would like to display all the CharFields I defined in the `CustomForm` and them to be editable. Thats how my AddUser looks like:

[image]

Comment: django User model extend AbstractUser which required fields are username, passwords and email , may be you need to add those fields to your form, the others fields are Optional.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the built-in UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth.forms instead of extending ModelForm.

This way you don't have to override the save method to set the password, however you'll need to add the `username`, `password1` and `password2` fields to your form, or it won't pass validation.

Comment: hey i just noticed and did that, I also specified the fields to be shown in admin.py with *add_fieldsets* and it shows fields which are unfortunately not editable

Comment: You do realize that the `UserCreationForm` already has all of the fields in your custom form, right? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I use the allauth-app and in my case the creationform has only the fields from my login-profile which is UserProfile and I also need the normal User fields.

Comment: I think you need to re-word your question to include that information, but I'm still not clear as to what your actual question is.

Comment: Well its at the bottom of the text. Maybe its not that comprehensive but I want to display the charfields I defined in the CustomForm. Sofar I only see the labels in admin-page without any possibility to enter text. Then I would like to store the input.

Comment: Are you also overriding the template for the change form? There's no reason I can think of as to why those fields in particular would show up as disabled, or not have text inputs at all.

Comment: Im not overriding the template. Im pretty puzzled too. They dont have any text-input fields. Funny but if I display the "username" field it kinda has input-field but its the exception.